# CRUD went wrong and heading to home page before doing things

Tags: php, html

It was a simple PHP script that I built years ago, then today I tried the same thing and something bad happened.

Chronology: I opened up the admin page, which is I can adding my content and it is already hosted in public html and this website I build has 2 years working in the same domain. But when I want to adding the new article in 3 days ago, it went like jumpy or some kind of error but I'm afraid I code no error in here, I don't know what to say for this problem.

After filling the title and the description, it just doing fine.
But when the submit button clicked, it headed to where it shouldn't be headed (to the home page). Where it should be heading is the addArticle.php=success, not the home page. It is confusing me because I don't know what was just happened, it works great for last 2 years. please help.

This is my 4th day for looking this trouble, and I still don't know why and what might be the problem. I did a `var_dump` and `die` but it wasn't the clue.

This is the main code in `addArticle.php`:

```
<?php
include 'core/function/crudArticle.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = ['articles_title', 'articles_description'];
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'All fields must be choosen and must not empty';
            break 1;
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (strlen($_POST['articles_description']) <= 10) {
            $errors[] = 'Article description must be greater than 10 characters';
        }
    }
}

?>
    <div class="psychologView">Add More Article</div>
<?php
if ($_GET['addArticle'] === 'success') {
    ?>
    <div class="confirmation">
        New Article has been added
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <ul class="psychologData container">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <li>
                <?php
                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                    $articleData = [
                        'articles_title'       => $_POST['articles_title'],
                        'articles_description' => $_POST['articles_description']];


                    addArticle($articleData);
                    $sequence = 1;
                    $sequenceQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `articles_id` FROM `articles` ORDER BY `articles_id`") or die(mysql_error());
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sequenceQuery)) {
                        mysql_query("UPDATE `articles` SET `sequence`=" . $sequence . " WHERE `articles_id` = " . $row['articles_id']);
                        $sequence++;
                    }
                    header('Location: articles.php?addArticle=success');
                    exit();
                } elseif (empty($errors) === false) {
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }
                ?>
            </li>
            <li><input type="text" class="form-control" name="articles_title" size="50" placeholder="Judul Article"/></li>
            <li>
<textarea name="articles_description" class="form-control ckeditor" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Isi Article">
</textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="display:flex;"><input class="submitButtons" type="submit" value="" style="margin-right:15px;"/><a class="backButtons" href="articles.php"></a></div>
        </form>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And this is the function page I created just for the article CRUD, I think it doesn't involve. But I will make sure you guys really look at what I code.

`crudArticle.php`:

```
<?php
function addArticle ($articleData) {
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($articleData)) . '`';
    $data   = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $articleData) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `articles` ($fields) VALUES($data)") or die(mysql_error());
}

function updateArticle ($editID, $updateData) {
    $update = [];
    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');

    foreach ($updateData as $fields => $data) {
        $update[] = '`' . $fields . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE `articles` SET" . implode(', ', $update) . "WHERE `articles_id` = $editID") or die(mysql_error());
}

function id_exists ($page_id) {
    $page_id = sanitize($page_id);
    $query   = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`articles_id`) FROM `articles` WHERE `articles_id` = '$page_id' ");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated - look into pdo and mysqli.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I'm not using PDO man, I'm using the old fashion and simplest one. the scripting.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs is that true a mysql can be deprecated? then how should i'm going through this? should I start over the code?? make a new one????

Comment: @riverrhun mysql is already deprecated in php 7 :-) , take a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [pdo](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: @hassan thx hassan, i think i would like to change to mysqli

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thx m8

Comment: What the other commenters means is that the PHP `mysql_` *functions* are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` functionality or `PDO` instead, in PHP. The MySQL database system itself is not (yet) deprecated!

Comment: @martin yea i just got that, thx mate

Comment: @riverrhun np man good luck :)